# Script that uses MySQL query to automatically remove output

Tags: bash, mysql

I have this query that outputs updates older than 7 days from a database. How would I make a script that takes the MySQL statement and puts it into a script to be executed by cron.

```
echo "select name, reported_at from nodes where reported_at < curdate() -7;" |
mysql dashboard
```

Sample output:

```
name    reported_at
xadf.edu    2012-03-21 14:39:02
xadf.edu    2012-03-22 15:30:01
adsfsadf.edu    2012-03-14 14:40:02
ekdahlj.edu 2012-03-23 03:40:04
adfasdf.net 2012-03-21 14:42:02
eqrsdr.edu  2012-03-15 14:42:02
qwerwfva.edu    2012-03-13 14:42:03
qerqwer.edu 2012-03-23 14:40:01
adfasde.edu 2012-03-05 17:42:03
bsfdgs.edu  2012-03-23 15:20:01
adfadsf.edu 2012-03-23 14:43:01
```

Comment: What do you have exactly? All I see is a path & a report output or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a file *~/path/to/myquery.sql*:

```
select name, reported_at from nodes where reported_at < curdate() -7;
```

And to edit your crontab execute

```
crontab -e
```

And in your crontab add a line

```
* * * * * mysql dashboard < ~/path/to/myquery.sql > ~/path/to/query/output
```

To edit how often this command is run, you have to edit the five *'s at the start of that line. To understand how to do this properly, you can check out [this page](http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

Just save it in a file, then redirect it into the `mysql` tool in your crontab.

```
* * * * * mysql ... < savedstatements.sql
```